# Switching values in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

So basically I am learning some basic java and I am currently writing a little "game" that tells you which button to click and if you click the correct one you receive a point. The buttons are defined as b1, b2, b3, and b4. The text on them says "Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3", and "Button 4".

What I wish to accomplish is each time I click a button, the values are reassigned randomly so that the b1 text for example might say "Button 3". But it would be random. I used Java random to get it to work how I want but now I need to solve the problem of having the buttons being assigned the same values. For example, b1 and b3 might both be named "Button 2". I'm not sure how to go about solving this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated. It is kind of frustrating me.

Ok so here is my code.... finally. Have a terrible internet connection atm.

**I put comments where I need the help**

```
import javax.swing.*;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


private JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
private JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 2");
private JButton b3 = new JButton("Button 3");
private JButton b4 = new JButton("Button 4");
private static JLabel label = new JLabel();
private static JLabel label2 = new JLabel("You currently have 0 points.");
private JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
private int points = 0;
private int randomButton;


public Gui() {
    super("Button Game");
    newLabel();
    setSize(400, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    b4.addActionListener(this);


    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    p.add(b1,c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    p.add(b2, c);
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 2;
    p.add(b3, c);
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 3;
    p.add(b4, c);
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    p.add(label, c);
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 4;
    p.add(label2, c);

    add(p);

}


public void rearrangeButtons() {

    //HERE IS WHERE I AM HAVING THE PROBLEM
    //b1.setText("Button " + randomButton);
    //b2.setText(newText);
    //b3.setText(newText);
    //b4.setText(newText);
}

public static int random(int range) {
    return (int)(java.lang.Math.random() * (range+1));
}


public static void newLabel() {
    switch(random(3)) {
    case 0:
        label.setText("Press button 1");
        break;
    case 1:
        label.setText("Press button 2");
        break;
    case 2:
        label.setText("Press button 3");
        break;
    case 3:
        label.setText("Press button 4");
        break;
    }
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String number = label.getText();



    if (e.getSource() == b1) {
        if (number.endsWith("1")) {
        points++;
        newLabel();
        } else {
            points = 0;
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == b2) {
        if (number.endsWith("2")) {
        points++;
        newLabel();
        } else {
            points = 0;
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == b3) {
        if (number.endsWith("3")) {
        points++;
        newLabel();
        } else {
            points = 0;
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == b4) {
        if (number.endsWith("4")) {
        points++;
        newLabel();
        } else {
            points = 0;
            newLabel();
        }
    }

    rearrangeButtons();
    label2.setText("You currently have " + points + " points.");    

}
}
```

Comment: Sure. Please edit and show us your code.

Comment: Please post your code where you assign the value to your buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) gives you an easy way to do this:

Declare your button text in a `List`:

```
List<String> myList = 
    new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"));
```

Every time you want to change the text on the buttons, shuffle List and assign:

```
Collections.shuffle(myList);
b1.setText(myList.get(0));
b2.setText(myList.get(1));
b3.setText(myList.get(2));
b4.setText(myList.get(3));
```

Comment: It would work for assigning values but not randomly would it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. This does exactly what you asked how to do.

Comment: Thanks it did work, my bad. Was encountering a different probelm. I'm new to the site, is there a way to rep/thank like on forums?

Comment: @Chawbee Accept my answer - the checkmark up there to the left (You don't have enough rep to upvote it yet). Thanks!

Comment: I accepted it but I need 15 rep to rep you :\ But I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: Brian's way of using Shuffle is better; forgot about that method, haha. My bad. Ignore this answer and use that.**

Create an ArrayList of your strings with `"button 1", "button 2", "button 3", "button 4"`

Every time a button is clicked, create an ArrayList that is a copy of the above array (not a copy of the reference). eg: `ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(intialArrayList);`

Then use `JButton#setText` and Math.Random() to choose one of those strings for the first button. **Every time you choose a string, delete the string from the copy.** (that would make it impossible to set a button text twice). 
Then repeat with the remaining buttons, but make sure the random number generated is first between 0-3, then 0-2, then 0-1.

eg:

```
int j = 3;
ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(initialArrayList);
for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++) {
    //int rand = generate random number between i and j
    String text = copy.get(rand);
   // setText(text) for each b1, b2, b3, b4;
   // copy.remove(text);
   j--;
}
```

Create a separate method for this so you don't have to keep typing this in for each `actionPerformed` method.

That's just how I would do it.

Comment: Either way, this isn't the best way to do it. `Shuffle` as Brian mentioned, is much quicker and cleaner.

Comment: Like I said, I am relatively new to programming. You can probably tell by the code I posted. I'm not exactly sure how to use arraylists so maybe you could post some pseudocode next to your example you posted?

Comment: It might be better it use a Set and keep filling it until you have the required number of numbers...but the idea is sound ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe each time you want to reset the text of your buttons you build a list of the 4 texts "Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3", "Button 4". Randomly pick one, assign it to b1, and then remove it from your list which would now have only 3 available texts left. Randomly choose again from your remaining list of 3 and assign that to b2. Continue until your list of available texts is empty (or 4 times in this case). When you need to reset these texts again just reset your list of available texts back to "Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3", "Button 4" and repeat.